# How to reference JS and CSS rails assets in production with a URL?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

In my Rails production environment, I want to have a certain JS file and certain CSS file on my server that are not precompiled and included in the asset pipeline. In other words, I want to be able to reference the files with a URL, like this:

```
https://mywebsite.com/example/my_javascript_file.js
```

How do I do this, or where do I place the files on my server so that they can be referenced in this way in production?

I could add these files to the public directory, is that best practice?

Comment: Is it just that you don't want these files compiled into application.js / application.css, or that you want a URL without a fingerprint?

Comment: Both, I'd like to be able to send out a URL that points directly to the standalone file.